# How do I get the video thumbnail of a Facebook video?

Tags: html, video-thumbnails

Here's a video:

```
https://www.facebook.com/Sample-Video-607728429342897/
```

And it's mobile version:

```
https://m.facebook.com/607728429342897/videos/607739209341819
```

How would I extract the thumbnail?

Using the mobile version and Ctrl+C+I, here's what could be the part of the source code that generates an image, I'm really not sure, but in any case it doesn't translate to an image url from which I can copy the image:

```
<i class="img _lt3 _4s0y" style="background: url('https\3a //scontent-atl3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.13418-10/121905236_1661898423987672_8420672770556658120_n.jpg?stp\3d cp0_dst-jpg_e15_p173x172_q65\26 _nc_cat\3d 100\26 ccb\3d 1-6\26 _nc_sid\3d ccf8b3\26 _nc_ohc\3d 1zH-3qWxPSUAX8wdbSf\26 _nc_ht\3d scontent-atl3-2.xx\26 oh\3d 00_AT_nIWd3fiubUkchrE8IxGm6YqSMEzPGacPYZ23-WuLYsQ\26 oe\3d 6288C31B') no-repeat center;background-size:100% auto;-webkit-background-size:100% auto;padding-bottom:56%;" data-sigil="playInlineVideo"></i>
```

Also see:

- [How to extract the direct FB url of a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978051/how-to-extract-the-direct-facebook-video-url#46813221)?
- [How do I get the YT thumbnail of a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)?

Snapshot:

[image]